# React-Native - Cannot read property "cloneWithRowsAndSections" of undefined

Tags: android, json, listview, react-native, datasource

I'm doing a simple `ListView` with section headers a la this tutorial:

https://medium.com/@darylrowland/reactnative-listview-with-section-headers-99a6714282c3#.627c88ikm

and I'm stuck for days on the part when the `ListView` uses its `datasource`.

The class's `constructor` and the json object which is the source for the data:

```
    export class ProductListScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

var ds = new ListView.DataSource({

  rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
  sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2
})
    this.state = {
      location: {
          products: [
            {
              name: "Paprika baburaw",
              class: "3",
              price: "20",
              measure_unit: "7",
            },
            {
              name: "Paprika babura",
              class: "3",
              price: "20",
              measure_unit: "7",
            },
            {
              name: "Paprika  2",
              class: "3",
              price: "20",
              measure_unit: "7",
            },
            {
              name: "meso 2",
              class: "1",
              price: "20",
              measure_unit: "7",
            },
            {
              name: "meso 2",
              class: "1",
              price: "20",
              measure_unit: "7",
            },
            {
              name: "sir",
              class: "4",
              price: "20",
              measure_unit: "7",
            },
          ],
          vendor: {
                name: "OPG xy",
                adress: "Mije Stuparica 4",
                e_mail: "wololo@gmail.com",
                telephone: "0922423425",
          }
        },
      }

  }
```

My `ListView` inside the render is defined like this (takes `sortProducts()` as `datasource`):

```
          <ListView
      dataSource={this.sortProducts()}
      renderRow={this.renderRow}
      renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
      renderSeparator={(sectionID, rowID) => <View key={rowID}/>}/>
```

And the render methods fo the rows and sections are also functional.

The function:

```
  sortProducts() {
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
      sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2
    })
    var productClassMap = {}
      this.state.location.products.forEach( function (productItem) {
        if(!productClassMap[productItem.class]) {
          productClassMap[productItem.class] = []
        }
      productClassMap[productItem.class].push(productItem)
    })
  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(productClassMap)
  })
  return productClassMap
  }
```

So the function tumbles the object and makes the `class` element of the `product`  the object's key which should serve as `SectionHeader` (1, 3 and 4 in this object).

The problem lies when i try to set the state at the end of a function, and gives the error in this question's title.

```
        dataSource: this.state.ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(productClassMap)
```

I'm guessing the error doesn't have much in common with the rest of the `ListView`, but I've put everything here so the context is clear.

What am I doing wrong? I'm banging my head for days.. Any pointers and suggestions are most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not initialization `ds` in state anywhere, thus it is undefined when you use it.

In your `sortProducts()`, change 
`dataSource: this.state.ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(productClassMap)` to `dataSource: ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(productClassMap)`

As the variable `ds` is initialized before in function, this should work fine.